# Script for renaming files using text file containing alternate file names

Tags: scripting, rename

I have a folder containing thousands of files:

```
file1.jpeg
file2.jpeg
file3.jpeg
```

etc.

I have a text file containing a list of new filenames I want to substitute:

```
old_filename     new_filename
file3.jpeg       my_dog.jpeg
file1.jpeg       my_cat.jpeg
file2.jpeg       my_goat.jpeg
```

etc.

I am looking for a script to rename all the files in the folder using the new filenames (or append the new name as a prefix to the original filename).

I think I need something that will search the folder, compare the name to the text file and then rename the file accordingly.

The lists and files are not sorted in any way.

Comment: So you're basically need something that prefixes `mv ` to every line in your file that you can pipe to your shell?

Comment: For example `sed -n '2,$ p' <your_file> | sed 's/^/mv /' | bash`

Answer (score 2):

First ensure you have a backup before trying this.

Your examples fortunately have no spaces in oldname and newnames, and no mention of sub-directories (all in same directory) so if all of the lines in your list look that way

1. have `rename_rules.txt` in the same directory as your images
2. cd into this directory
3. run:

   ```bash
    eval "$(sed 's/^/mv /g' rename_rules.txt )"
   ```

   - where `rename_rules.txt` contain only pairs of `oldname newname` on each line
   - `sed` is used to convert your `rename_rules` into `mv oldname newname`
   - `eval` is then used to execute it, thus the file gets renamed

disclaimer: no validation or file checking is built into this simple short script at all, which is why I said the first thing to do is to be sure you have a backup in case one of your rename `oldname newname` pairs happens to contain a mistake, then you can at least start over from the backup

Comment: Thanks,  giving it a try but get:   mv: missing file operand
Try `mv --help' for more information.
mv: missing file operand
Try `mv --help' for more information.

Comment: I am newly familiar to sed - I use sed to convert html pages (that I download) into text files containing download links for the DownThemAll plugin in Firefox.  I'm trying to figure out how to rename the files I download to something resembling that of the website the file came from - not just the useless gibberish download link from blogspot or somewhere else.

Comment: Basically mv was not getting any input for one or more lines -- do you have empty lines in your rename_rules.txt ?

Comment: Just thought - there are two options I can live with: 1. rename or append to the filename of the file  or 2. move the file into a new folder with a folder name that is specified in a text file as stated above - basically, search for a filename - if it exists in the search folder move the file into a new folder with a folder named specified in a text file.

Comment: IT WORKED - MY MISTAKE - I WAS LOOKING IN MY BACKUP FOLDER - D'OH. - filenames in working directory were changed .